# PyCharm - always show inspections

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, lint

PyCharm displays little bars on the scroll bar for things like code warnings. This feature is called "inspection".

If you move the mouse cursor over a bar, it shows a preview of the code annotated with the inspection.

I find this really fiddly, and I'd actually like full inspection notices to be displayed *all the time* in the normal editor, just like it appears in the small preview.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

[image: screenshot showing an example PyCharm inspection]

Comment: `if code not in ...`

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible using PyCharm. You could use PyDev, which does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Press `Alt+6`
- Or, click "Problems" on the bottom-left

[image: problems button]

- Or click the error icons at the top-right of the text editor.

[image: error icons]

This gives a list of problems for the file open in the currently active tab. It automatically updates when you change tabs:

[image: problems list]

Answer (score 2):

Using the default keymap, you can use `F2` to jump to the next highlighted error and then `Ctrl+F1` to show the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this PyCharm's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/3.0/inspection-tool-window.html) there seems to be an *Inspection Tool Window* which *displays inspection results on separate tabs.*.

You can access the tool window through menu **Code | Inspect Code**.

I just tried it and it showed a tab like this:

[image]